# GPS Distance and speed not updating

Tags: objective-c, ios7, gps

I have the following code which is meant to get the distance travelled by the user, and return their speed in two labels.

.h file

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
    #import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>


    @interface pointToPointViewController : UIViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
    {
        CLLocationManager *locManager;
        CLLocationSpeed speed;
        NSTimer *timer;
        UILabel *speedText;
        UILabel *locationText;
        UILabel * distanceText;

        CLLocationSpeed currentSpeed;
        float fltDistanceTravelled;

    }

    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *locationText;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *distanceText;

    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *timer;
    -(float)getDistanceInKm:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *speedText;
```

.m file

```
import "pointToPointViewController.h"
#define kRequiredAccuracy 500.0 //meters
#define kMaxAge 10.0 //seconds
#define M_PI   3.14159265358979323846264338327950288   /* pi */

@interface pointToPointViewController ()

@end

@implementation pointToPointViewController
@synthesize timer;
@synthesize speedText;
@synthesize distanceText;
@synthesize locationText;
-(void)startReadingLocation{
    [locManager startUpdatingLocation];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    CLLocationManager *locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate=self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    speedText = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    NSString *speedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"speed is %.2f", currentSpeed];
    speedText.text = speedString;


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
}



- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"new->%d old->%d",(newLocation==NULL),(oldLocation==NULL));

    if(newLocation && oldLocation)
    {
        fltDistanceTravelled +=[self getDistanceInKm:newLocation fromLocation:oldLocation];
    }
}

- (void)timeIntervalEnded:(NSTimer*)timer {
    fltDistanceTravelled=0;
    [self startReadingLocation];
}


-(float)getDistanceInKm:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    float lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2;

    lat1 = newLocation.coordinate.latitude  * M_PI / 180;
    lon1 = newLocation.coordinate.longitude * M_PI / 180;

    lat2 = oldLocation.coordinate.latitude  * M_PI / 180;
    lon2 = oldLocation.coordinate.longitude * M_PI / 180;

    float R = 6371; // km
    float dLat = lat2-lat1;
    float dLon = lon2-lon1;

    float a = sin(dLat/2) * sin(dLat/2) + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dLon/2) * sin(dLon/2);
    float c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a));
    float d = R * c;

    NSLog(@"Kms-->%f",d);

    return d;
    NSString *distancestring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f.2",d];

    distanceText.text = distancestring;



}
```

when i run the app, using the "freeway drive" location option, none of the text fields are updating, and the console isn't providing any information (i.e. the distance travelled)

could anyone please identify where in my code i need to fix?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In your method:

```
- (float)getDistanceInKm:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

The return statement is before the setting of the text and therefore the setting is never executed, to fix this move the return statement to the end of the method.

Comment: i have moved the lines of code, but still none of the labels are updating.